# is requestAnimationFrame run concurrently with other scripts?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

does requestAnimationFrame run the functions queued up on it concurrently with other *normally* run javascript, i.e. from user input or from setTimeout/setInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs on the same single thread like everything else (except Workers), so yes.

Comment: so whilst a function that was queued up in rAF is running, it is certain no other client javascript can be running?

Comment: I thought this was the case but I had a really tricky bug in my code I couldn't figure out but I have now and everything is awesome again, thanks.